# solve the iterative integral equatio

Tags: integral-equations, iteration

The following code is incorrect, please specify my mistakes

```
y[0, t_] := 4 - 3 t;
y[n_, x_] := 4 - 3 x + 
  0.59489439*
   NIntegrate[ 
    t (1 - x) {D[y[n - 1], {t,2}] - 3/2 y[n - 1, t]^2}, {t, 0, x}] +
  0.594894
   NIntegrate[ 
    x (1 - t) {D[y[n - 1], {t,2}] - 3/2 y[n - 1, t]^2}, {t, x, 1}]
Table[{n, x, y[n, x]}, {n, 1, 3}, {x, .1, 1, .1}]
```

Comment: Here the integrand contains derivative term also. I couldn't get the answer. Please anyone correct my mistakes

Comment: Please edit your question and show the complete formula `y[n,x]=...`

Comment: Equation edited

Comment: `y[n-1,x]''` makes no sense. Please check out how to write [partial derivatives](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html). Something like `D[y[n-1,x], {x,2}]`.

Comment: The function y[] and Derivative y'''[] depend on t not
 x!?

Comment: `y[0,x_]:=4-3x; y[n_,x_]:=4-3x+0.59489439*Integrate[x(1-t)(D[y[n-1,t],{t,2}]-3/2 y[n-1,t]^2),{t,0,x}]+0.594894*Integrate[x(1-t)(D[y[n-1,t],{t,2}]-3/2 y[n-1,t]^2),{t,x,1}];
Table[{n,x,y[n,x]},{n,1,3},{x,.1,1,.1}]` Test that very carefully to see if it is correct.

Comment: Yes, Thank you sir

Comment: In the above equation, for n=20(number of iterations) the program still running(taking more than hour), why it's happen?, anything wrong in it?

Comment: You defined your problem so calculating `y[20,.1]` must calculate `y[19,.1]` must calculate `y[18,.1]` ... Try this change `y[0,x_]:=4-3x; y[n_,x_]:=y[n,x]=4-3x+0.59489439* Integrate[x(1-t)(D[y[n-1,t],{t,2}]-3/2 y[n-1,t]^2),{t,0,x}]+0.594894* Integrate[x(1-t)(D[y[n-1,t],{t,2}]-3/2 y[n-1,t]^2),{t,x,1}]; Table[{n,x,y[n,x]},{n,1,3},{x,.1,1,.1}]` which will use more memory to remember past calculations and may speed this up. It is very late here and I cannot test this now. I will try to test this in the morning and see if it is faster. Please test this to see if it is correct and faster or not.

Comment: It works quickly for n= 5, next I trying for n=7, its still running

Comment: @ThenmozhiS Please correct your integral equation(question). Bill used in both integrals factor `x(1-t)`, in your question there are different factors!

Comment: Thank you sir,  corrected now

Answer (score 0):

Here an approach to solve the problem using `NestList`

```
sol = NestList[
Function[y,FunctionInterpolation[4 - 3 x +  
0.59489439*Integrate[t (1 - x) (D[y[ t], {t, 2}] - 3/2 y[ t]^2), {t, 0, x}] + 
0.594894*Integrate[x (1 - t) (D[y[ t], {t, 2}] - 3/2 y[ t]^2), {t, x, 1}], {x, 0,1 }]    
] (* Ende Function *)
, 4 - 3 #   &  (* Startwert *)
, 10]
```

The iterated solutions swap between two fixpoint functions, one of them `4-3x`

```
Plot[Through[sol [x]], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, but I didn't get output

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer (initial condition double `&` was wrong)

Comment: I'm a beginner to Mathematica, so that I'm having lot of doubts and doing mistakes while writing the code. Please help me to correct it

Comment: Try to copy my code and run it. You only have to check the equations(I don't know the background).

Comment: Yes sir, I did the same, but didn't get the answer

Comment: What did you get for `sol`?

Comment: Still in running state

Comment: @ThenmozhiS. Using `MMA 12.0`, code works for me.

Comment: But I'm using  Mathematica 11.0

Answer (score 0):

There is an exact solution that coincides with the numerical solution @UlrichNeumann at the first iterations:

```
y[0] = 4 - 3 t; $Assumptions = a > 0 && b > 0; Table[
 y[n] = With[{y = y[n - 1]}, 
   4 - 3 x + 
    a*Integrate[
      t (1 - x) (D[y /. x -> t, {t, 2}] - 3/2 (y /. x -> t)^2), {t, 0,
        x}] + b*
     Integrate[
      x (1 - t) (D[(y /. x -> t), {t, 2}] - 3/2 (y /. x -> t)^2), {t, 
       x, 1}]], {n, 1, 3}]
```

Here we get a very long expression even at the third iteration. Compare `y[n]`and numerical solution of the equation obtained by Ulrich Neumann

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[y[n] /. {a -> 0.59489439, b -> 0.594894}, {n, 1, 3}]], {x, 0, 
  1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
sol = NestList[
   Function[y, 
    FunctionInterpolation[
     4 - 3 x + 
      0.59489439*
       Integrate[
        t (1 - x) (D[y[t], {t, 2}] - 3/2 y[t]^2), {t, 0, x}] + 
      0.594894*
       Integrate[
        x (1 - t) (D[y[t], {t, 2}] - 3/2 y[t]^2), {t, x, 1}], {x, 0, 
      1}]] (*Ende Function*), 4 - 3 # &  (*Startwert*), 4];

Table[Plot[{y[i] /. {a -> 0.59489439, b -> 0.594894}, 
   sol[[i + 1]][x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> i], {i, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Figure 1]
From the discussion it became clear that the author wanted to solve the equation `y''[t]==(3/2)y[t]^2` with boundary conditions `BCs={ y[0]==4, y[1]==1}`. This problem has an exact solution `y=4/(1+t)^2`. But then the iterative scheme was built incorrectly. To build a converging process, we need to put in my scheme

```
y[0] = 4 - 3 x; $Assumptions = a > 0 && b > 0; Table[
 y[n] = With[{y = y[n - 1]}, 
   y + a*Integrate[
      t (1 - x) (D[y /. x -> t, {t, 2}] - 3/2 (y /. x -> t)^2), {t, 0,
        x}] + b*
     Integrate[
      x (1 - t) (D[(y /. x -> t), {t, 2}] - 3/2 (y /. x -> t)^2), {t, 
       x, 1}]], {n, 1, 3}]
```

We can optimize the parameters `a, b` using the exact solution

```
FindMinimum[
 Sum[(y[1] - 4/(1 + x)^2)^2, {x, 0, 1, .1}], {{a, .59}, {b, .59}}]

(*{0.00051333, {a -> 0.556396, b -> 0.653769}}*)
```

Let's check how different the solution at each iteration is from the exact solution

```
Table[Plot[(y[i] /. {a -> 0.5563963697722774`, 
      b -> 0.6537687187362005`}) - 4/(1 + x)^2, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> i], {i, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

We see that with optimized parameters the process converges quite quickly. Change the numerical scheme @UlrichNeumann using non-optimized parameters

```
sol = NestList[
   Function[y, 
    FunctionInterpolation[
     y[x] + 0.59489439*
       Integrate[
        t (1 - x) (D[y[t], {t, 2}] - 3/2 y[t]^2), {t, 0, x}] + 
      0.594894*
       Integrate[
        x (1 - t) (D[y[t], {t, 2}] - 3/2 y[t]^2), {t, x, 1}], {x, 0, 
      1}]] (*Ende Function*), 4 - 3 # &  (*Startwert*), 4];
```

and compare with the exact solution

```
Table[Plot[(sol[[i]][x]) - 4/(1 + x)^2, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> i], {i, 2, 4}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

We see that with non-optimized parameters the process converges worse (but converges!). Change the parameters to the optimal ones. We see that the process apparently converges and stops after the third iteration

```
    sol1 = NestList[
   Function[y, 
    FunctionInterpolation[
     y[x] + 0.5563963697722774`*
       Integrate[
        t (1 - x) (D[y[t], {t, 2}] - 3/2 y[t]^2), {t, 0, x}] + 
      0.6537687187362005`*
       Integrate[
        x (1 - t) (D[y[t], {t, 2}] - 3/2 y[t]^2), {t, x, 1}], {x, 0, 
      1}]] (*Ende Function*), 4 - 3 # &  (*Startwert*), 7];

Table[Plot[(sol1[[i]][x]) - 4/(1 + x)^2, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> i], {i, 2, 7}]
```

[image: Figure 4]
A numerical solution with nonoptimized parameters behaves similarly
[image: Figure 5]

Comment: Thank you sir, other than graph, for the table of numerical values up to 20 or 30 iterations which code can we use?

Comment: @ThenmozhiS First, what do you want to get? Secondly, what equation do you want to solve? You should describe the problem in mathematical language. We decided on the equation at our discretion. Do `a` and `b` really have such values in your equation?

Comment: While solving the second order boundary value problem y''[t]=(3/2)y[t]^2 with BCs: y[0]=4, y[1]=1 by using Fixed point iterative scheme(2 step), we obtain the above mentioned volterra integral equation. In that scheme a sequence (a_n) appeared, for optimum value for a_n, it taken as 0.59... In the above eqution a=b=a_n

Comment: @ThenmozhiS Boundary value problem `y''[t]==(3/2)y[t]^2` with `BCs={ y[0]==4, y[1]==1}` has exact solution `y=4/(1+t)^2`.

Comment: yes sir, but we are trying to apply fixed point iteration scheme to obtain solution for higher order boundary value problem(I got this idea somewhere else).

Comment: @ThenmozhiS See update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: @ThenmozhiS Are you satisfied with the answer or will we continue the discussion?

Comment: Yes sir, am satisfied, thank you for your guidance.

Comment: In my code use `Table[{n, x, (y[n] /. {a -> 0.5563963697722774, b -> 0.6537687187362005})}, {n, 1, 3}, {x,.1,1.,.1}]`